# Is the strings.xml in the values folder necessary?

Tags: android

I want to have different language values folders (Ex: values-en, values-de, values-fr). Every folder will have a version of the strings.xml file. My question is: do I have to keep the default strings.xml file in the values folder, or one of the specific strings.xml files will be used if I deleted the default file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default strings.xml is used when values are missing from your language specific strings.xml files. It is a good place to keep things like application names etc which may not change. In future, if your app needs to be localised to a non-Latin script, then you can then overwrite the Latin script application name with a localised non-Latin script in the language specific strings.xml file.